# Uncaught ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined Richfaces 3.x to 4.x

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, seam2

I'm going through a massive migration of this old application. It was using JSF1.2, Seam 2.2 and Richfaces 2.x. We migrated it to JSF 2.1, Seam 2.3 and Richfaces 4.x. After the migration I can't load any css nor js.

i've got this errors from firebug:

> orderForm.seam:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
>   defined(anonymous function) @ orderForm.seam:9 orderForm.seam:17
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined

Here is my template xhtml (edited to replace the src attribute for name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib">


<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>company name</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/favicon.ico" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="/private/stylesheet/theme.xcss" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="/private/stylesheet/default.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="/private/stylesheet/CalendarControl.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="/private/stylesheet/theme.css" />
<h:outputScript name="/private/js/jquery.js" />
<h:outputScript name="/private/js/idle-timer.js" />
<h:outputScript name="/private/js/jquery.formatCurrency.js" />
<h:outputScript name="/private/js/CalendarControl.js" />
</h:head>
<body>
    <ui:insert name="head" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

    <rich:popupPanel style="background-color: white;" id="eula"
        autosized="true" width="500" moveable="false" resizeable="false">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Eula" />
        </f:facet>
        <center>
            <iframe src="eula.html"
                style="height: 410px; width: 500px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #666; padding: 8px;" />
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton action="#{identity.logout()}" value="I Decline" />
                <h:commandButton action="#{authenticator.markEulaAgreed()}"
                    value="I Accept" />
            </h:form>
        </center>
    </rich:popupPanel>



</body>
</html>
```

and i tried to simplify as much the composition to track the problem so:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://agilers.com/taglib"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    template="layout/2columns-even.xhtml">



</ui:composition>
```

here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>


    <!-- RichFaces -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Suppress spurious stylesheets -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Change load strategy to DEFAULT to disable sending scripts/styles as 
        packs -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>402</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>406</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>407</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>408</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>409</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>410</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>411</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>412</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>413</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>414</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>415</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>416</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>417</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>501</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>502</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>504</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>505</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>




    <context-param>
        <description>CAS renew</description>
        <param-name>renew</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/taglib/company.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <display-name>HSTS Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>HSTSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.company.filter.HSTSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HSTSFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <display-name>IE9 Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>ie9filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.company.filter.IE9Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ie9filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionIdFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.company.filter.SessionIdFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionIdFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>https://www.company.com/login/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>https://www.company.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https://www.company.com/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>https://www.company.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.company.servlet.SessionServletListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>1000000</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>
    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>companyEntityManagerFactory</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>company</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>




</web-app><servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>
    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>companyEntityManagerFactory</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>company</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>




</web-app>
```

EDIT 2: I verified that on the old version the resources tab of firebug the resources from JSF and richfaces wasn't there and still it was working and the resources added in the xhtml was there, correctly, while on the migrated version there was just the JSF and richfaces but all of them with the .seam extention and my explicit declared resources wasn't there. Another interesting fact is that it just happens if i put this at the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

otherwise it wont't bring anything to the loaded resources.

Given the new web.xml with  error has changed to :

**Uncaught ReferenceError: A4J is not defined**

Comment: Well, for one `h:output*` [tags have no src attribute](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html). But if you have any Seam filter on it might be interfering with resources.

Comment: Try disabling the resource servlet, and check what's generated in `<head>`, the resources are not being linked correctly.

Comment: disabling Seam Resource servlet didn't make difference but I have some more information added to the question description

Comment: Loading your own jquery will cause this; get rid of the `/private/js/jquery-*`

Comment: @MichaelLemos Were you able to resolve the issue? I have a similar `RichFaces is not defined` error and haven't been able to find a solution as of yet either

Comment: Resolved as this lib "A4J" was removed from richfaces 4 as described here:       https://access.redhat.com/solutions/882623

Answer (score 0):

This lib "A4J" was removed from richfaces 4 as described here: access.redhat.com/solutions/882623